# Is it possible to inverse inheritance using a Python meta class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaprogramming, metaclass

Out of curiosity, I'm interested whether it's possible to write a meta class that causes methods of parent classes to have preference over methods of sub classes. I'd like to play around with it for a while. It would not be possible to override methods anymore. The base class would have to call the sub method explicitly, for example using a reference to a base instance.

```
class Base(metaclass=InvertedInheritance):

    def apply(self, param):
        print('Validate parameter')
        result = self.subclass.apply(param)
        print('Validate result')
        return result


class Child(Base):

    def apply(self, param):
        print('Compute')
        result = 42 * param
        return result


child = Child()
child.apply(2)
```

With the output:

> Validate parameter
>   Compute
>   Validate result

Comment: You've tagged this Python 3, but you're using the Python 2 metaclass syntax, which Python 3 completely ignores. If you want to specify a metaclass on Python 3, you should do `class Foo(metaclass=Whatever)`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, corrected.

Comment: What is `self.subclass` meant to be there?  If `Child.apply` is meant to return `Base.apply`, and `child.subclass` is `Child`, then `self.subclass.apply` will be the same as `Child.apply` and will still return `Base.apply`.  The attribute-accessing mechanism won't "know" whether you're trying to get the attribute from outside code or from inside the inheritance-reversing machinery.  Do you want this reverse lookup to work when accessing attributes directly on the class, or just when accessing them via instances?

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, I see. It's meant as a way to access the child methods. It could be a helper object containing references to the child methods.

Comment: This sounds like flax https://github.com/google/flax - I was searching exactly about the same thing, right because of flax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about making lookups on *instances* go in reverse order (not classes), you don't even need a metaclass.  You can just override `__getattribute__`:

```
class ReverseLookup:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        cls = self.__class__
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__[attr]
        # Using [-3::-1] skips topmost two base classes, which will be ReverseLookup and object
        for base in cls.__mro__[-3::-1]:
            if attr in base.__dict__:
                value = base.__dict__[attr]
                # handle descriptors
                if hasattr(value, '__get__'):
                    return value.__get__(self, cls)
                else:
                    return value
        raise AttributeError("Attribute {} not found".format(attr))

class Base(ReverseLookup):
    def apply(self, param):
        print('Validate parameter')
        result = self.__class__.apply(self, param)
        print('Validate result')
        return result

class Child(Base):
    def apply(self, param):
        print('Compute')
        result = 42 * param
        return result

>>> Child().apply(2)
Validate parameter
Compute
Validate result
84
```

This mechanism is relatively simple because lookups on the class aren't in reverse:

```
>>> Child.apply
<function Child.apply at 0x0000000002E06048>
```

This makes it easy to get a "normal" lookup just by doing it on a class instead of an instance.  However, it could result in confusion in other cases, like if a base class method tries to access a different method on the subclass, but that method actually doesn't exist on that subclass; in this case lookup will proceed in the normal direction and possibly find the method on a higher class.  In other words, when doing this you have be sure that you don't look any methods up on a class unless you're sure they're defined on that specific class.

There may well be other corner cases where this approach doesn't work.  In particular you can see that I jury-rigged descriptor handling; I wouldn't be surprised if it does something weird for descriptors with a `__set__`, or for more complicated descriptors that make more intense use of the class/object parameters passed to `__get__`.  Also, this implementation falls back on the default behavior for any attributes beginning with two underscores; changing this would require careful thought about how it's going to work with magic methods like `__init__` and `__repr__`.

Comment: Thanks. If there is a chain of inheritance `A<-B<-C`, would `self.__class__.apply()` in `A` find the method of `B` or the leave class `C`? Also, in a inheritance diamond `A<-B,C<-D`, I'd like to use cooperative inheritance in reverse order, so that everywhere calling `self.sub.apply()` goes `A, B, C, D`.

Comment: @danijar: Calling `apply` on an *instance* of C will call the method on A, and then `self.__class__.apply()` in A will call it on C.  If you really want to handle all kinds of inheritance trees, I'd suggest you completely ignore Python's existing inheritance mechanism and implement the entire thing yourself (e.g., using class attributes called `ReverseParent` or whatever instead of actually inheriting from the "parent").  But to be honest I don't see the point of that.  If you want inheritance to be *completely* reversed, just reverse your inheritance graph and then use regular inheritance.

Comment: When "just reversing the inheritance graph" it should be mentioned that one can use ``__subclasscheck__`` (i.e. override it in a metaclass as desired) to retain the originally intended "is-A" relation between the classes and subclasses.